# Sync two repositories in one project + Sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

There are two repos:

1: My Repo --> (Test.git)
2: Company Repo --> (Test.git)

I done my changes in my repo, And some other people do their changes on company repo. Can I sync those two repos in one project.Where I see all the changes and merge accordingly?

Comment: Is your repo derived from your company repo?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I sync those two repos in one project.Where I see all the changes
>   and merge accordingly?

It depended on the relationship between `My Repo` and `Company Repo`.

**Case 1:** Ff `My Repo` fork from `Company Repo` (or `Company Repo` fork from `My Repo`), you can sync, like this

https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork

**Case 2.** If `My Repo` and `Company Repo`  has no relationship, you cannot sync in true way of git. You must use diff software (such as Beyond Compare, https://www.scootersoftware.com/), then merge manually.